# How can I force a block not to be cached for unauthenticated users?

Tags: drupal, drupal-blocks, drupal-cache

I have a php block which I would like to be refreshed on every page load/reload. Although I have disabled all caching under Site Configuration -> Performance the block is still being cached. Although I've googled a great deal on this I haven't found any definitive answers. Surely there must be a way to properly disable caching of content for unauthenticated users!

I'm using Drupal 6.20 and the site address is www.cygnet-rcDOTorg.uk (The block in question is the Twitter feed on the left sidebar 'Latest Tweets'...

BTW - The PHP in is using the Twitter Pull module. I have changed the configuration for the module for a 1 minute cache so I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: Could your hosting company be providing some caching?  I know, for example, that if you host with Acquia they additionally cache pages for anonymous users using Varnish... Or could it be browser caching?  Did you test to see whether when you open the site on a different browser whether new tweets are reflected?

Comment: Good thought Boriana, thanks, but that's not it.

Comment: Go for http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile and use the javascript api instead of the twitter pull module.